# TImer stops working after I click the button to stop/start it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Timer completely stops working it won't start again after I stop it how can I fix this?

I am trying to have it toggle from 1 button first click toggles it if a grid is visible.

if the grid is not viable it will stop the timer/won't start the timer
 I am having the timer reference a different grid based on the same thing as 
 above but for a different function.

I'm pretty new to C# and wpf.

If I need to give you guys more information for this just ask
 This code is in a different window from the mainwindow.

The reference to the mainwindow is AS which I have a lot higher up in the code for this window.

This window is being referenced by the mainwindow to open/close.

```
private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer1;

public void InitTimer()
{
    timer1 = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000); // in miliseconds
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AS.Vis.Visibility != Visibility.Visible == false)
    {
        AS.Vis.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
    else
    {
        AS.Vis.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        Fin();

        timer1.Start();
    }
}

private void Auto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (AS.tmr.Visibility != Visibility.Visible == false)
        {
            AS.tmr.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            AKS.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            AKS.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            AKS.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen);
            AKS.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            AS.tmr.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            InitTimer();
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not call InitTimer() more than once (e.g. in the constructor). And do not call timer1.Start() in the Tick handler. It is already running.

Comment: @Clemens just tried that and the timer won't stop I had it like that because it would stop the timer but not resume it

Answer (score 0):

Is the method *Auto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)* the only method who can start the timer (in the event *timer1_Tick* the timer is also started, but first if I understand your code snipped correct, the method *Auto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)* must call)? When is this method called? Maybe you can add this to the question.

If the method (*Auto(...)*) is called, can you check the *if-condition*. Maybe it will never go again into the *else* case.

Comment: Auto is a button that I press to trigger the event and the else is called but if I leave it on it on then close the settings window and try to disable aka pressing the button again it crashes the entire app